# How to store all address values in single key using sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

I have 7 fields in address page.
I want to store all fields value in single key using SharedPreferences.I know how to store single value.. I don't know how to store all the values.

My code here:

```
SharedPreferences shared = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("tagAddress", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.putString(text, line1.toString());
editor.commit();
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the type of the `line1` variable ?

Comment: each time update the preference value with new value

Comment: format your all value as single value and then save.

Comment: To get the value from EditText, use `line1.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 1):

Since `line1` is a `EditText` you should use `line1.getText().toString()` and to store multiple value in a single entry, you can do this:

```
editor.putString(text, line1.getText().toString() + "|||" + line2.getText().toString() + "|||" + ...);
```

and to get then:

```
String[] values = shared.getString(text,"").split("\\|\\|\\|");
```

Comment: I got an error in retrive value,  cannot resolve symbol 'text' in this line String[] values = shared.getString(text,"").split("|||");

Comment: @Appu `text` is the key you've used to store the values.

Comment: If i put the values in Log means its show like these: [Ljava.lang.String;@350e3c5c..... How to show user gave string

Comment: That is because the `values` variable is a `String` array, you can log it like this `Arrays.toString(values)` and to get a specific value you can do this `values[0]`

Comment: @Appu that is because `|` is a special regex character, I've edited my answer to fix this.

Comment: Thank you very much... Finally only one thing.. If i put like this means Log.d("Line 1:",values[0]);
            Log.d("Line 2:",values[1]);
            Log.d("City:",values[2]);
            Log.d("Zipcode:",values[3]);
            Log.d("Country:",values[4]);
            Log.d("State:",values[5]);
            Log.d("Landmark:",values[6]);   Its throw an error like these java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6...

Comment: @Appu that is because there are only 6 values in the array and you are trying to get the 7th one. Make sure you're saving 7 values and you should check the length of the array before getting the values.

Comment: I got it... Thank you so much

Comment: @Appu if this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have to try to add data in ArrayList store in arraylist then send data 
same as you can access that data in to different class..

```
ArrayList<string> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();

listdata.add(str1);
listdata.add(str2);
```

..... as so on

then store in shared prefrences like this

```
SharedPreferences shared = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("tagAddress",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.putString("listdata", listdata.toString());
editor.commit();
```

and access also another class with same key "listdata"

```
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

SharedPreferences prefs = referenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.getBoolean("listdata", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a sqlite database instead. Of course, it is more complex. But its worth any efforts. Believe it. SharedPreferences in addition requires much memory space. So this class is useful for a little
variables, not for array!

A good tutorial i found. It works
http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/